# Why can't I paginate although I use the same string in WHERE clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I use 'will-paginate' gem to use pagination.
This code below works very well.

```
@cafe = Cafe.where('id = 7 or id = 6 or id = 3 or id = 2 or id = 1').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
```

But, when I use the code below,

```
@caves_ids = @caves.collect(&:id)
@sql = 'id = '+@caves_ids[0].to_s
for i in 1..@caves_ids.size-1
  @sql += ' or id = '+@caves_ids[i].to_s
end
@cafe = Cafe.where(@sql).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
```

four posts come out well in the first page, but when I click on page 2 button, the below error message appeared:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ")": syntax error: SELECT  "caves".* FROM "caves" WHERE (id = ) LIMIT 4 OFFSET 4
```

`@sql` and `'id = 7 or id = 6 or id = 3 or id = 2 or id = 1'` are definitely same!!!(Because I confirm it hundreds of times .)

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `@caves_ids` array is empty.
Anyway, I advice you use next solution:

```
@cafe = Cafe.where(id: [7,6,3,2])
```

In your case array is `@caves_ids`, but when it will be empty, you does not get syntax error.

Comment: No. It is clearly not empty because value of `@sql`  is  `'id = 7 or id = 6 or id = 3 or id = 2 or id = 1'`...

Comment: Look at generated SQL command `...SELECT  "caves".* FROM "caves" WHERE (id = )...` -> so `@caves_ids` must be empty array. Could you check it again?

Comment: @llya - Yes. When I use it without pagination, 5 posts appear.

Comment: @LongNguyen - I put this code `<%= @caves_ids %> ` in erb file, It returns `[ 7, 6, 3, 2, 1]`. It is never empty...

Comment: I just write in my rails console `User.where("id = 5 or id = 6 or id = 7 or id = 8").paginate(page: 1, per_page: 3)` and it works.

Comment: `@cafe = Cafe.where(id: @caves_ids).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)`, I think it is better code

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way

```
@caves_ids = @caves.pluck(:id)
@caves_ids.count.each do |id|
 @sql=@sql+' or id='+id.to_s
end
@cafe = Cafe.where(@sql).paginate(:page=>params[:page],:per_page => 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but @caves_ids is array.
This is error message.
`undefined method 'pluck' for #<Array:0x000000103cbb70>`